# When refreshing a component, state variables are not assigning values in React

Tags: reactjs, state

I'm developing dynamic UIs by using backend data.

[image: App architecture for tab compoonent]

as you can see using Route A I'm getting the metadata and I'm currently assigning these metadata to TabnavigationCenter Component. when I'm using the **Route A** everything works fine. but when I tried to refresh the page it won't work and throws an error like this...

[image: Error Alert]

Here's my code:

```
class TabNavigationCenter extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        const { homeState: { integrityOptions }, homeActions: { getDataIntegrityOptions } } = this.props;
        const tabTitle = parseInt(localStorage.getItem(LOCAL_STORAGE.DIMENSION_MAPPING_TAB_TITLE));

        this.state = {
            value: 0,
            inputValue: '',
            userAccess: null,
            selectedDimensionMetaData: []
            //Todo : addProviderDrawerOpen:false
        }
        this.child = createRef()

    }

    componentDidMount() {
        const { authState: { privilege }, homeActions: { getHomePage, getDataIntegrityOptions }, homeState: { integrityOptions } } = this.props
        const tabTitle = localStorage.getItem(LOCAL_STORAGE.DIMENSION_MAPPING_TAB_TITLE);

        getDataIntegrityOptions();
        const tabView = parseInt(localStorage.getItem(LOCAL_STORAGE.DIMENSION_MAPPING_TAB_ID));
        this.setState({
            value: tabView ? tabView : 0,
            userAccess: privilege ? privilege : parseInt(localStorage.getItem(LOCAL_STORAGE.PRIVILEGE_KEY)),
            selectedDimensionMetaData: this.props.homeState.integrityOptions.map(
                (integrityOption) => {
                    if (integrityOption.title == tabTitle) {
                        return integrityOption;
                    }
                }
            )
        })
        // getProviderMappingGridConfigs();
        localStorage.getItem(LOCAL_STORAGE.DIMENSION_MAPPING_TAB_ID) == null ? localStorage.setItem(LOCAL_STORAGE.DIMENSION_MAPPING_TAB_ID, 0) : null
        localStorage.setItem(LOCAL_STORAGE.APP_AUTO_OPEN, false)
    }

    render() {
        const { homeState, homeState: { integrityOptions }, dimensionMappingActions, dimensionMappingState, isLoading, homeActions, history } = this.props
        const { value, userAccess, selectedDimensionMetaData, addProviderDrawerOpen } = this.state;
        const { providerGridConfigs } = dimensionMappingState;

        let backdrop;
        if (addProviderDrawerOpen) {
            backdrop = <Backdrop close={this.backdropClickHandler} />;
        }

        return (
            <div className="App">

                <div className='dimension-mapping-container'>
                    {backdrop}
                    <Row>
                        <button className='dimension-mapping-navigate-button' onClick={() => { this.goToHomePage() }}>
                            <span>&#8592; Home</span>
                        </button>

                        <button className='dimension-mapping-navigate-button' style={{ float: "right" }} onClick={() => { this.goToAdminCenter() }}>
                            <span>&#10005;</span>
                        </button>
                    </Row>

                    <Row className='dimension-mapping-header-container'>
                        <Col sm={6}>
                            <p className="dimension-mapping-header">{selectedDimensionMetaData[0] !== undefined && selectedDimensionMetaData[0].title}</p>
                        </Col>
                        <div className='text-right'>
                            <Col sm={2}>
                            </Col>
                            <Col sm={4}>
                                <button className='add-dimension-button' onClick={() => { this.openAddDimensionDrawer() }}>
                                    {selectedDimensionMetaData[0] !== undefined ? selectedDimensionMetaData[0].addRecordButtonLabel : null}
                                </button>
                            </Col>
                        </div>
                    </Row>
                    {((userAccess != null && userAccess != ENUMS.PRIVILEGES.VIEWER) && value === 0 || value === 1) && <GridExport data={dataSetProvider} headers={providerHeaders} clientName={homeState.header_info.clientName} />}
                    <Row>
                        <TabBar value={value} onChange={this.handleTabClickEvent} aria-label="ant example" >
                            <TabOption label={selectedDimensionMetaData[0] !== undefined && selectedDimensionMetaData[0].dimensionTabLabel} badgeVisibility={false}>

                            </TabOption>
                            {
                                selectedDimensionMetaData[0] !== undefined && selectedDimensionMetaData[0].hasUnmappedDimensionsTab ? (
                                    <TabOption
                                        label={selectedDimensionMetaData[0] !== undefined && selectedDimensionMetaData[0].mappingTabLabel}
                                        badgeVisibility={true}
                                        notificationCount={selectedDimensionMetaData[0] !== undefined && selectedDimensionMetaData[0].notificationCount}>
                                    </TabOption>
                                ) : null
                            }
                        </TabBar>
                        {value === 0 &&
                            <MappedDimensionTab
                                dimensionMappingActions={dimensionMappingActions}
                                dimensionMappingState={dimensionMappingState}
                                isLoading={isLoading}
                            />

                        }
                        {value === 1 &&
                            <div>Add a new tab here</div>
                        }
                    </Row>
                </div>

            </div >
        )
    }
}

export default TabNavigationCenter
```

Can someone help me to understand what I'm doing wrong here ? Thank you!!